# SQL-HIVE-PIG -Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming

There are 5 columns in each line and those  5 columns are commonly separated by comma

```
1 column is name
2nd column is date_of_purchase
3rd column is product
4th column is mode of payment
5th column is total_amount
```

Hope you understood what data it contains

```
surender,2014-03-09,TV,OFFLINE,20000
surender,2014-01-01,Mobile,ONLINE,18000
Raja,2014-09-21,Laptop,ONLINE,30000
Surender,2014-10-12,Laptop,ONLINE,40000
Raja,2014-FEB-11,MusicSystem,ONLINE,2000
Kumar,2014-07-09,Ipod,OFFLINE,4000
Kumar,2014-06-08,TV,ONLINE,20000
Raja,2014-11-07,SPeakers,OFFLINE,8000
Kumar,2014-10-18,Laptop,ONLINE,30000
```

What i need is i want to see how much amount each person has spent via online mode and offline mode

basically i need the reducer output should like below

```
surender   OFFLINE   20000
surender   ONLINE    58000
Raja       OFFLINE   8000
Raja       ONLINE    32000
Kumar      OFFLINE    4000
Kumar      ONLINE    50000
```

And the final output should be like this:

```
surender 20000  58000
Raja     8000   32000
Kumar     4000   50000
```

You can give me a hive or pig query or either a mapreduce program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = LOAD 'file_name' using PigStorage(',') as (name:chararray,date:chararray,product:chararray,mode:chararray,total:long);
B = GROUP A BY (name,mode);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group.name as name,group.mode, SUM(total) as total;
D = GROUP C BY name;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE group, C.total;
```

if your data like the sample you provided has different spellings then you need to convert to uppercase before grouping

Comment: @AnuragSingh, please accept answers that answers your questions!